# addon "mesh extras" not available in 2.7

Tags: add-on

When I use 2.67 everything is ok but when I try to find extra meshes they are not available even though I selected them in user preferences?

Comment: Welcome Robert :) In the User Preferences > Addons > Search for "Extra" and you will find "Add Mesh:Extra Objects".

Comment: He said he already did. Probably just didn't hit *save user settings*

Answer (score 4):

- Go to *File > User Preferences > Addons*
- Search for `extra`
- Make sure *Supported Level* is set to **Community**
- *Categories* to **All**
- Tick the box at the very right
- Optionally *Save User Settings* to enable it by default
- Go to *3D View > Add > Mesh*, the icon-less entries are from the Extra Objects addon.

[image: Add Mesh: Extra Objects]

Answer (score 0):

Go into user preferences, find the `Addon` tab, find the addon, enable the addon, then click `Save User Settings`. You may not have clicked this at first. I know this is not a bug because it worked on my machine just a few days ago.

Comment: *Save User Settings* is only required to enable it permanently.

Comment: He wanted it that way. i think.

Comment: @CoDEmanX I'd assume that was your down vote? Why? It's not a great answer, but certainly not a bad one. When it's just "okay" it's always better to simply not vote.

Comment: I think it's beside the point, which is the need to change the support level to community.

Comment: @CoDEmanX it worked and still works for me without doing that

Comment: Alright then, vote revoked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Blender 2.76 press on your keyboard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> to get to *User Preferences* shortcut. Then search extra, check the mesh extra.