# I cannot add a Sqorus

Tags: add-on

I tried [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19740/addon-mesh-extras-not-available-in-2-7) method.
I am able to add "Add Mesh: Extra Objects", extras pop up but there is no sqorus.
In documentation, it says that it has an "[Add Sqorus](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Add_Extra)" function but I am unable to find it.

Please help :).

Comment: the documentation here is out of date.
the sqorus object was removed some time ago

Answer (score 2):

Sqorus is a cube with a hole inside it.

Add Mesh -- Extra Objects -- Beam Builder
And apply the settings as shown below [image]